# Replacing %~dp0 in VBScript

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I can't find anything to replace %~dp0 in my VBScript

```
On error resume next
Set shell= createobject("WSCRIPT.SHELL")
Shell.run "%~dp0test.bat", vbhide
```

Comment: Why you ever need `%~dp0` then can call `.Run` with relative path like "test.bat"

Answer (score 5):

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
GetTheParent = fso.GetParentFolderName(Wscript.ScriptFullName)
```

Taken from here:

- [how to get working drive and directory?](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/how-to-get-working-drive-and-directory-m1248.aspx)

To use the obtained value in your script, add a reference to the variable where you need its value. For instance:

```
Shell.run GetTheParent & "\test.bat", vbhide
```

Comment: Where do I have to place it? I tried this and it didn't work
    On error resume next
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    GetTheParent = fso.GetParentFolderName("Wscript.ScriptName")
    Set shell= createobject("WSCRIPT.SHELL")
    Shell.run "h4x0r.bat", vbhide

Comment: I've made some fixes and added a usage example.

Answer (score 0):

To get the folder the executing .VBS resides in:

```
type dp0.vbs
Option Explicit
Dim oFS : Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
WScript.Echo "WScript.ScriptFullName", WScript.ScriptFullName
WScript.Echo "oFS.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)", oFS.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName
)


cscript dp0.vbs
WScript.ScriptFullName E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\tools\jscript\ijs\dp0.vbs
oFS.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName) E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\tools\jscript\ijs
```

Comment: I still don't get how to apply this to my script.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
   set objShell = Createobject("wscript.shell")
    strPath = Left(WScript.ScriptFullName, Len(WScript.ScriptFullName) - Len(WScript.ScriptName))
    Shell.run strPath & "test.bat", vbhide
```